# image not showing in angular 4 after checking checkbox

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 4. I want to show an image when the checkbox is checked. But its not working. My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chec" [(ngModel)]="check1" value="http://www.clipart-library.com/data_images/432133.jpg">

<img src="{{check1}}" height="100" width="100">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing till I will answer your question. Two-way data binding is bad pattern and You shouldn't use it, even Angular creators stopped to improve it since Angular 2.

I recommend using here something called `*ngIf` - this is angular conditional instruction which allows you to check conditions in HTML.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="chec" [(ngModel)]="check1">
 <div *ngIf="check1">
     You will see this only when checkbox is checked!
 </div>
```

Addiotional - do not bind file path to ngModel.As @Rakesh said it's logical value. What is more even object 2-way binded with path value, will constantly check for file path changes and it would probably slow down your application.

Answer (score 1):

.HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chec" (change)="checkOnClick($event)" value="http://www.clipart-library.com/data_images/432133.jpg">
  <img src="{{check2}}" height="100" width="100">
```

.TS

```
export class App {
  check2:string = "";
  constructor() {

  }
  checkOnClick(e:any){
    if(e.target.checked){      
      this.check2 = e.target.value;
   }
  }
}
```

Plunker URL : https://plnkr.co/edit/S6f01oy0YQ8e94mQg7Uv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Value will not be work when you are using  `[(ngModel)]="check1"` this is only show true or false. If you want to show image on checked then you can change your code like this

```
<img src="{{check1 ? 'url of image when checked': 'do what ever you want if not checked'}}" height="100" width="100">
```